# POST call with same headers and same request body gives different response?

Tags: bash, http, google-chrome, post, curl

I was using a website (mysite1.com) , and 3 screens deep from the login screen is the screen that I want to reach using **bash and curl** & simulating the exact same request that would have gone through the browser. What I mean by simulating is sending exactly the same headers (including referer & origin).

Here is what is happening:

1. I was able to cross the login screen & screen 2 by simulating the browser behaviour
2. Now, I am stuck at screen 3. The POST call that goes to the mysite1 server is same as the browser would send, every bit of it.
3. To do the POST call of 3rd Screen , I create a **form on localhost** with **action="URLOf3rdScreenOnMysite1"** and method=post. And before submitting, I change the referer origin and other headers using a browser extension.
4. This is generating the request that I mentioned in point 2.
   However,the first two calls for screen1 and 2 were in bash.

There are **no cookies** being used by mysite1. Session_id is there as a GET query string parameter. I assumed that probably the server is keeping a track of the flow of URLs requested, but I got the error response even when I followed the flow using bash.

The POST call in the 3rd screen returns different response (an error response) when I try to simulate and returns the , even when the flow of URLs requested is the same in both the cases. How can this be possible? How is the server coming to know that these request are different, the one from browser and the other from bash + last-screen-from-browser? Are there any other parameters involved except for **Headers + POST Data + URLs requested**? Maybe a different **connection** established when calling the 3rd screen from browser?

Comment: Not enough details.

When I encounter this, it is usually because meta redirect is being used or some other similar thing.

Also are you using FOLLOWLOCATION and SSL options?

Comment: Can you tell me what other details might be required? Also, FollowLocation is needed for 302 redirects only not for 200 status requests, plus the 3rd screen is requested over the browser so it manages all of them.